# How to get chickens from trading post to one of my empty pastures?

Tags: banished

I have two empty pastures with the maximal size of 20x20 tiles. Then I traded 6 chickens. None of this chickens have ever found the way to the prepared pastures.

a) How can I 'force' new bought chickens to move from the trading post to one of the empty pastures?
b) Is it possible, that my prepared pastures are too big for chickens?
c) How can I avoid that traded chickens will be sold at the market?
d) Do you know other reasons why traded animals disappears?

*BTW: If I click on the empty [pasture](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Pasture), I can choose between cattle, sheep and chickens.*

Comment: And did you choose the chickens and assigned some workers to the pasture?

Comment: To be sure: Has the worker to be assigend to the pasture BEFORE the trade or does it work, if the chickens are already in the mini-pasture beside the trading post? What exactly do you mean with 'did you choose the chickens'?

Comment: It shouldn't matter - I think I managed to even create the pasture after getting the animals. So it would make sense that you should be able to assign the workers after getting the animals. And by "choosing the chickens" I mean you chose chickens as the animal to be bred on that one pasture, in the same way as you choose crops for a farm.

Comment: In my second attempt, I activated the pasture with a Herdsman, doublechecked 'Chicken' as animal to be bred and then the LIVING Chickens (bought at the trading post) run by itself to this pasture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have probably bought Chicken which are dead Chickens. To have them in the Pen you need to buy living Chickens from the Livestock merchant.

Your c) statement that the "Chickens" meat is being sold at the market confirms this theory.

A simple way to see if it is a live or dead chicken(s) is that the value of live chickens are 400-500 and chicken meat is worth 3.

[See trade screenshot for living Chickens](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Livestock#Chicken)

Comment: That could be possible! In my second attempt to buy living chickens in the trading post, everything works well. The six chickens run by itself to the prepared pasture. Now I already own a lot of them! :)

Comment: Hmmm.  You must have thought those chickens seemed a bit cold. =D

Comment: The real clue is the value: live chickens are worth 400-500, chicken meat is worth 3.

Comment: I did the same thing with new seeds -- "why can't I plant this wheat"?

Comment: Same applies for seeds, their value is ~2500 (or ~3000 if ordered). For the final product the value is much lower.

Comment: i hadn't realized seeds are more expensive when ordered. good to know.

Comment: @DLeh *everything* is more expensive when ordered.  Convenience has a cost.